# Using ForwardDiff.jl for a function of many variables and parameters Julia

Tags: julia

The github repo for ForwardDiff.jl has some examples. I am trying to extend the example to take in addition to a vector of variables, a parameter. I cannot get it to work.

This is the example (it is short so I will show it rather than linking)

```
using ForwardDiff
x = rand(5)
f(x::Vector) = sum(sin, x) .+ prod(tan, x) * sum(sqrt, x);
g = x -> ForwardDiff.gradient(f, x);
g(x) # this outputs the gradient.
```

I want to modify this since I use functions with multiple parameters as well as variables. As a simple modification I have tried adding a single parameter.

```
f(x::Vector, y) = (sum(sin, x) .+ prod(tan, x) * sum(sqrt, x)) * y;
```

I have tried the following to no avail:

```
fp = x -> ForwardDiff.gradient(f, x); 
fp = x -> ForwardDiff.gradient(f, x, y); 

y = 1
println("test grad: ", fp(x, y))
```

I get the following error message:

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching (::var"#73#74")(::Array{Float64,1}, ::Int64)
```

A similar question was not answered in 2017. A [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45820892/13952307) led me to [here](http://www.juliadiff.org/ForwardDiff.jl/latest/user/limitations.html) and it seems the function can only accept one input?

> The target function must be unary (i.e., only accept a single argument). ForwardDiff.jacobian is an exception to this rule.

Has this changed? It seems very limited to only be able to differentiate unary functions.

A possible workaround would be to concatenate the list of variables and parameters and then just slice the returned gradient to not include the gradients with respect to the parameters, but this seems silly.

Comment: Just wondering: is there a reason not to use `Zygote` or `ReverseDiff` here?

Comment: @OscarSmith There is not, I am playing around with autodiff, and this is where I started. Would ReverseDiff or Zygote solve my problem?

Comment: Zygote is the pot of gold at the end of the rainbow. Make that the answer, and you get the checkmark. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I personally think it makes sense to have this unary-only syntax for ForwardDiff. In your case, you could just pack/unpack `x` and `y` into a single vector (nominally `x2` below):

```
julia> using ForwardDiff

julia> x = rand(5)
5-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.4304735670747184
 0.3939269364431113
 0.7912705403776603
 0.8942024934250143
 0.5724373306715196

julia> f(x::Vector, y) = (sum(sin, x) .+ prod(tan, x) * sum(sqrt, x)) * y;

julia> y = 1
1

julia> f(x2::Vector) = f(x2[1:end-1], x2[end]) % unpacking in f call
f (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> fp = x -> ForwardDiff.gradient(f, x);

julia> println("test grad: ", fp([x; y])) % packing in fp call
test grad: [2.6105844240785796, 2.741442601659502, 1.9913192377198885, 1.9382805843854594, 2.26202717745402, 3.434350946190029]
```

But my preference would be to explicitly name the partial derivatives differently:

```
julia> ∂f∂x(x,y) = ForwardDiff.gradient(x -> f(x,y), x)
∂f∂x (generic function with 1 method)

julia> ∂f∂y(x,y) = ForwardDiff.derivative(y -> f(x,y), y)
∂f∂y (generic function with 1 method)

julia> ∂f∂x(x, y)
5-element Array{Float64,1}:
 2.6105844240785796
 2.741442601659502
 1.9913192377198885
 1.9382805843854594
 2.26202717745402

julia> ∂f∂y(x, y)
3.434350946190029
```

Comment: An issue with the first, which concatenates parameters onto variables, is that parameters often out number variables, so this is a lot of extra work. I don't need to spend the flops calculating gradients for parameters. I do however like the second approach

Comment: Sure, if you need the derivatives with respect to `x` only and you have many parameters, then you just need to differentiate the closure `x -> f(x, params...)` (instead of the single `y` variable), which would generalize the first line in my 2nd code block above.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick attempt at a function which takes multiple arguments, the same signature as `Zygote.gradient`:

```
julia> using ForwardDiff, Zygote

julia> multigrad(f, xs...) = ntuple(length(xs)) do i
         g(y) = f(ntuple(j -> j==i ? y : xs[j], length(xs))...)
         xs[i] isa AbstractArray ? ForwardDiff.gradient(g, xs[i]) : 
           xs[i] isa Number ? ForwardDiff.derivative(g, xs[i]) : nothing
         end;

julia> f1(x,y,z) = sum(x.^2)/y;

julia> multigrad(f1, [1,2,3], 4)
([0.5, 1.0, 1.5], -0.875)

julia> Zygote.gradient(f1, [1,2,3], 4)
([0.5, 1.0, 1.5], -0.875)
```

For a function with several scalar arguments, this evaluates each derivative separately, and perhaps it would be more efficient to use one evaluation with some `Dual(x, (dx, dy, dz))`. With large-enough array arguments, `ForwardDiff.gradient` will already perform multiple evaluations, each with some number of perturbations (the chunk size, which you can control).

Comment: It looks to me like Zygote is fairly easy and more or less good to go out of the box?

Comment: Zygote is reverse mode, a different algorithm which works well for many-input one-output functions, but is more complicated. Both are good, but far from perfect. ForwardDiff is simpler, more stable, usually easier to debug. (Tracker & ReverseDiff are two older reverse-mode libraries which are also simpler than Zygote.)